# Print Server para ticketeras

Tags: impresora

Necesito saber si alguien ha usado o sabe si son compatibles los Print Server tplink modelos TL-PS110U y TL-PS310U con las ticketeras (impresoras) Epson TM-U220 y Bixolon SRP-270 (ambas USB).
Agredezco de antemano sus respuestas.